# Using a url as a slug in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following route in my Express project:

```
router.get('/statusCode/:url', function(req, res){
    //finds the http status code of a webpage
    try {
        req.param.url = utils.formatUrl(req.param.url);
    } catch (err) {
        res.render('siteError', {error: "Invalid url"});
    }
    utils.getStatusCode(req.params.url)
    .then(function(statusCode){
        req.statusCode = statusCode;
        renderPage(req, res);
    }).catch(function(err){
        utils.errorHandler(err);
    });
});
```

I want to be able to do `localhost:3000/statusCode/http://www.google.com`, but the route never gets called on the server. How can I map urls to go to this route?

Comment: Does it work with a more basic route like `localhost:3000/statusCode/test`? Is the problem that you're sending a URL into the route?

Comment: @MattFletcher, `/test` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to encode URI string that you want to pass on. Then you can [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) on the server side and redirect the user to it.